# What does the slash do in 'case $1/$2' in shell script (/bin/sh)

Tags: shell, scripting, slash

Found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Hooks_in_/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep) example on the arch wiki

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    ;;
esac
```

and can't make out if it's a logical operator or something else.

Comment: it matches the `/` in `pre/*` and `post/*`

Comment: It is a trick to test $1 and $2 at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing special here. The syntax for `case` is

```
case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
```

In the example in the question, `word` is built by combining `$1`, `/` and `$2`. `/` doesn't have a special meaning at all, it's just a character.

PS: Practically the usage is a bit strange, as the `$2` part afterwards gets matched against `*` so the value of `$2` doesn't really matter. One could, in the context described in the Wiki, also write

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  pre)
    echo "Going to $2..."
    ;;
  post)
    echo "Waking up from $2..."
    ;;
esac
```

But there might be cases where `suspend`, `hibernate` or `hybrid` (the possible values for `$2`) are relevant, so it's just a general pattern here.

Comment: maybe `$1` is `pre/heat` and `$2` is `oven` in which case your code would not match, but the original would ;-)

Comment: @mosvy True. But in the context of the script as explained on the Arch Wiki page linked in the question that's something which "should not happen". Haha.

Comment: They would not be equivalent in cases where `$1` is `pre/something`.